# cordova: plugin is not on npm:

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on cordova application. At the moment i am using external plugin. `com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser`

When i try to build the application from https://build.phonegap.com
it is faling with below error.

> Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this
>   plugin is not on npm: com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser@~1.0.0

I have added the plugin in config.xml

```
<plugin name="com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.0.0" />
```

I can see plugin in plugin directory on my local machine.
Any advise what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per their [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/16/git-plugins/) 
you can add plugins from git repositories.

so upload the plugin you have in local system to [GitHub](http://github.com) or [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) public repository and use it's path in your `config.xml` like following

```
// install plugin from a git repository (name is optional)
<plugin spec="https://github.com/example/cordova-plugin.git" source="git" />


// it doesn't have to be GitHub, it can be any git server
<plugin spec="https://bitbucket.org/example/cordova-plugin.git" source="git" />
```

you can checkout more options [in the Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/#Plugins)

Comment: Thanks Arpit. I am struggling to make it work. I am not able to use any external plugin for file picker. I thought no one answer. Thanks

Comment: could you please have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701051/file-picker-in-cordova might be you can put light on it.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine replying to 1st comment. as per their docs it should work. as far as answering goes, if question is well defined and proper like yours people will answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you got the cordova: plugin is not on npm while building the app try the following configuration  for phonegap/cordova plugins. Change Plugin name and 
value is the package name of plugin.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" value="CDVConnection" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" value="CDVLocation" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts"   value="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.5.3" />
```